# Parsing json data with random/unknown value data type for key

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-json

How to parse json data with random/unknown value type for keys?In below json data,key data can be a json object or string depending upon response from server.

Response 1(Json object)

```
 {
          "responseCode": 2,
          "responseMessage": "hi",
          "data": {
            "key": "Id",
            "value": "10312412",
            "key2": "Id2",
            "key3": "Id3"
          }
    }
```

Response 2(String)

```
   {
          "responseCode": 2,
          "responseMessage": "hi",
          "data": "String here"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is

```
Object data = response.get("data");
```

Though, you might be able to try

```
boolean gotObject = true;
String dataString = null;

// Try to request a JSONObject as a String
dataString = String.valueOf(response.optJSONObject("data"));

// If there wasn't a JSONObject, then try to get a String
if (dataString.isEmpty() || dataString.equals("null")) {
    dataString = response.optString("data");
    gotObject = false;
}
```

Then, you can try this

```
if (gotObject) {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataString);
}
```

Realistically, you should make a more consistent server API

Comment: thanks..i think it should be if (!dataString.isEmpty() || !dataString.equals("null")) ?

Comment: Nope, If it is empty or null, then there was no data there, so that means the value was not a JSONObject